# Connected Adwords account to GA and API V3 shows data, API v4 don't

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-ads-api, google-apis-explorer

Connected Adwords Account to Google Analytics.

Loaded data retrospectively (10 hours passed since loading).

Costs in reports:

- Google Analytics wed-interface - YES.
- https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/ - YES
- API V4 - NO. (I don't see exactly 1 row of newly connected data)

I know that Query Explorer uses API V3.

I think API V4 requires more time for new data to appear.

Can anyone confirm?

Comment: Nope should actually be faster with v4.  try testing here https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/analyticsreporting/v4/analyticsreporting.reports.batchGet  Tip setting up the post should be fun :o)    Actually i thought they had updated the Apis Exporter to v4  I will have to check